module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'model_selection'
Why does the code below return the error
module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'model_selection'

import sklearn
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x,y, test_size = 0.2)

but this one works fine:
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x,y, test_size = 0.2)

note that I did declare x and y as arrays.

In Python, when you import a module using a statement like
 import sklearn

you're essentially importing only the top-level module, and you do not automatically gain access to all the submodules or functions contained within that module. That's why you often need to import specific submodules like
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


Because you need to import sklearn.model_selection separately.
It will not come automatically with import sklearn.
You can either do:
import sklearn.model_selection

or
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

